# Generally slicing just the one element of a list/tuple?

Tags: python, linked-list, subclassing, slice

This `slice(-1,0)` fell out of a piece of actual code, it looks like a slice-wrap, nearly, but it isn't.

Comment: I suspect that an actual "slice-wrap" is would be another challenge.

In the case of a "nearly-wrapped" slice, the simple workaround is to drop the upper bound in just this special case:

```
AEIOU[-1:], AEIOU[-1:None], or (more quirkilly) AEIOU[-1:5]
```

The more general attempt: (I'm using: *Python 2.6.6*)

```
AEIOU[start%len(AEIOU): stop%len(AEIOU)] # simply struggles.
```

But given that negative member function `__getitem__` always works, it is a bit strange (dangerous) that a "nearly-wrapped" member `__getslice__` is simply returns something too short.

Questions:

1. Is there a specific design reason that a "near-wrapped" slice is short, rather then (maybe) raising a `IndexError: (list/string/tuple) index out of range" exception` ?
2. How can I create a subclass of list to manage this?
3. Is this handled differently in *Python 3.0* somehow?

Demo:

```
>>> AEIOU="AEIOU"
>>> for i in range(-len(),5,1): print "%-16s, %r, %r"%(slice(i,i+1,1),AEIOU[i],AEIOU[i:i+1])
... 
slice(-5, -4, 1), 'A', 'A'
slice(-4, -3, 1), 'E', 'E'
slice(-3, -2, 1), 'I', 'I'
slice(-2, -1, 1), 'O', 'O'
slice(-1, 0, 1) , 'U', '' # missing U...
slice(0, 1, 1)  , 'A', 'A'
slice(1, 2, 1)  , 'E', 'E'
slice(2, 3, 1)  , 'I', 'I'
slice(3, 4, 1)  , 'O', 'O'
slice(4, 5, 1)  , 'U', 'U'
```

I've noticed a general "workaround" is:

```
>>> i=-1; AEIOU[i:i%len(AEIOU)+1]
'U' # found U
```

Errata, slicing examples:

```
>>> s=3
>>> for i in range(-len(AEIOU),5,1): print "%-16s, %r, %r, %r"%(slice(i,i%len(AEIOU)+s,1),AEIOU[i],AEIOU[i:i+s], AEIOU[i:i%len(AEIOU)+s])
... 
slice(-5, 3, 1) , 'A', 'AEI', 'AEI'
slice(-4, 4, 1) , 'E', 'EIO', 'EIO'
slice(-3, 5, 1) , 'I', '', 'IOU'
slice(-2, 6, 1) , 'O', '', 'OU'
slice(-1, 7, 1) , 'U', '', 'U'
slice(0, 3, 1)  , 'A', 'AEI', 'AEI'
slice(1, 4, 1)  , 'E', 'EIO', 'EIO'
slice(2, 5, 1)  , 'I', 'IOU', 'IOU'
slice(3, 6, 1)  , 'O', 'OU', 'OU'
slice(4, 7, 1)  , 'U', 'U', 'U'
```

Comment: This is a [thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-October/634046.html) from the python mailing list discussing your question and other related implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

negative indices count down from the end of the list, but they can overshoot the beginning if they are large enough. When they overshoot they simply pin to the first item in the list.

```
items = range(10)
items[-10:-9]
# 0
items[-20:-9]
# 0
```

positive indices count up from the beginning of the list. They also pin at the end of the list if they overshoot:

```
items[9:10]
#[9]

items[9:100]
#[9]
```

unlike regular **getitem** access, an index outside list bounds is just clamped to the end. Usually this will return an empty slice:

```
items[99:100]
#[]

items[-99:-88]
#[]
```

The special case in your example arises because `'aeiou'[-1:0]`  is the same thing as `'aeiou'[4:0]` -- and since that's a slice with a negative length but a positive stride, it's empty. If you put in `'aeiou'[4:0:-1]` you'll get back `'uoie'`.

Because of the pinning behavior, there's no guarantee that returned slice will contain the same number of items as the distance between the specifiers. Slices make a nice idiom for getting items without prior bounds checks, which is the opposite of what I think you're asking for:

```
stuff = ['a','b','c']
d = stuff[11:12]
# []

stuff[11]
#IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you really need to know that your query is out of range you have to precheck the indices:

```
def strict_slice(the_list, begin, end):
    listlen = len(the_list)
    if begin > listlen or begin + listlen < 0:
        raise IndexError, 'start index out of bounds'
    if end + listlen < 0 or end > listlen:
        raise IndexError, 'end index out of bounds'
    return the_list[begin:end]


test = 'abcdefg'
strict_slice(test, 1, 3)
strict_slice(test, -10, 3)
# IndexError: start index out of bounds
strict_slice(test, 1, 20)
#IndexError: end index out of bounds
```

While you could subclass `list` to do this, it seems easier to me to use this recipe or just check for empty slices instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes** the tuple & list wrapping problem (over the "[-1:0]" boundary) can be patched with a "MixIn" class.

e.g.  **Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def wrapslice(*sl):
  if len(sl)==1: sl=sl[0]
  if isinstance(sl, int): return sl
  else:
    if not isinstance(sl,slice): sl=slice(*sl) 
    if None in (sl.start,sl.stop): return sl
    elif sl.start>=0 or sl.stop<0: return sl
    else: return slice(sl.start, None, sl.step)

class WrapMixin(object):
# Not sure how to use a decorator on a MixIn, so I use some "boilerplate" code...
  def __getitem__(self,sl):
    return super(WrapMixin,self).__getitem__(wrapslice(sl))
  def __setitem__(self,sl, value):
    return super(WrapMixin,self).__setitem__(wrapslice(sl), value)
  def __delitem__(self,sl):
    return super(WrapMixin,self).__delitem__(wrapslice(sl))

# Note: for __getslice__ [-1:2] converts to [-1+len:2]... 
#       i.e. add len to any -ve numbers! Ouch...
  def __getslice__(self,start,stop):
    if start>stop: stop+=len(self)
    sl=wrapslice(start,stop)
    return super(WrapMixin,self).__getslice__(sl.start, sl.stop)
  def __setslice__(self,start,stop, value):
    if start>stop: stop+=len(self)
    sl=wrapslice(start,stop)
    return super(WrapMixin,self).__setslice__(sl.start, sl.stop, value)
  def __delslice__(self,start,stop):
    if start>stop: stop+=len(self)
    sl=wrapslice(start,stop)
    return super(WrapMixin,self).__delslice__(sl.start, sl.stop)
  # Todo: def append/insert/append/iadd/radd ...

#class WrapString(WrapMixin, string): pass # FAIL
class WrapTuple(WrapMixin, tuple): pass # GOOD
class WrapList(WrapMixin, list): pass # GOOD

if __name__=="__main__": # test case
  aeiou=list("aeiou")
  AEIOU=WrapList("AEIOU")
  len_slice=3
  for i in range(-5,5,1): 
    vanilla=slice(i,i+len_slice)
    fixed=wrapslice(vanilla)
    print AEIOU[i]+"...","Vanilla:",vanilla,"vs Patched:",fixed
    print "  get_slice VANILLA: %15r -> PATCHED: %15r"%(aeiou[vanilla.start:vanilla.stop], AEIOU[vanilla.start:vanilla.stop])
    print "  get_item  VANILLA: %15r -> PATCHED: %15r"%(aeiou[vanilla], AEIOU[vanilla])
```

**Output:**

```
A... Vanilla: slice(-5, -2, None) vs Patched: slice(-5, -2, None)
  get_slice VANILLA: ['a', 'e', 'i'] -> PATCHED: ['A', 'E', 'I']
  get_item  VANILLA: ['a', 'e', 'i'] -> PATCHED: ['A', 'E', 'I']
E... Vanilla: slice(-4, -1, None) vs Patched: slice(-4, -1, None)
  get_slice VANILLA: ['e', 'i', 'o'] -> PATCHED: ['E', 'I', 'O']
  get_item  VANILLA: ['e', 'i', 'o'] -> PATCHED: ['E', 'I', 'O']
I... Vanilla: slice(-3, 0, None) vs Patched: slice(-3, None, None)
  get_slice VANILLA:              [] -> PATCHED: ['I', 'O', 'U']
  get_item  VANILLA:              [] -> PATCHED: ['I', 'O', 'U']
O... Vanilla: slice(-2, 1, None) vs Patched: slice(-2, None, None)
  get_slice VANILLA:              [] -> PATCHED:      ['O', 'U']
  get_item  VANILLA:              [] -> PATCHED:      ['O', 'U']
U... Vanilla: slice(-1, 2, None) vs Patched: slice(-1, None, None)
  get_slice VANILLA:              [] -> PATCHED:           ['U'] <= Found U!
  get_item  VANILLA:              [] -> PATCHED:           ['U']
A... Vanilla: slice(0, 3, None) vs Patched: slice(0, 3, None)
  get_slice VANILLA: ['a', 'e', 'i'] -> PATCHED: ['A', 'E', 'I']
  get_item  VANILLA: ['a', 'e', 'i'] -> PATCHED: ['A', 'E', 'I']
E... Vanilla: slice(1, 4, None) vs Patched: slice(1, 4, None)
  get_slice VANILLA: ['e', 'i', 'o'] -> PATCHED: ['E', 'I', 'O']
  get_item  VANILLA: ['e', 'i', 'o'] -> PATCHED: ['E', 'I', 'O']
I... Vanilla: slice(2, 5, None) vs Patched: slice(2, 5, None)
  get_slice VANILLA: ['i', 'o', 'u'] -> PATCHED: ['I', 'O', 'U']
  get_item  VANILLA: ['i', 'o', 'u'] -> PATCHED: ['I', 'O', 'U']
O... Vanilla: slice(3, 6, None) vs Patched: slice(3, 6, None)
  get_slice VANILLA:      ['o', 'u'] -> PATCHED:      ['O', 'U']
  get_item  VANILLA:      ['o', 'u'] -> PATCHED:      ['O', 'U']
U... Vanilla: slice(4, 7, None) vs Patched: slice(4, 7, None)
  get_slice VANILLA:           ['u'] -> PATCHED:           ['U']
  get_item  VANILLA:           ['u'] -> PATCHED:           ['U']
```

Note: **string** type cannot be subclassed, hence cannot be patched.
Also: Calls to members __getslice__ & __setslice__ with negative start:stop args are tricky because these arguments get 'fiddled with' by the interpreter... hence the additional patch code...